# FCM Custom notification sound

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have Firebase messaging with my andriod application. I am using Firebase to send push notifications. I want to change the default notification sound to a custom one. how can i do it ?

```
    Uri defaultSoundUri = 
    RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setLargeIcon(image)/*Notification icon image*/
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notif)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(image))
            ;


    NotificationManager notificationManager =  (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(id) /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: you can find [this](https://www.myflashlabs.com/custom-icon-sound-fcm-air-native-extension/) article very useful. It explains how you can handle custom sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" +R.raw.pop);
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

Use above code to add custom sound from resources.

The above code can be used if we are using Notification class.

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
```

As you are using NotificationBuilder, use the below code.

```
Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notifysnd);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setLargeIcon(image)/*Notification icon image*/
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notif)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(sound)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(image))
        ;
```

Comment: Where should i replace it ? Can we Modify above code with ours or ?

Comment: It [Worked ] Thank You Very Much Bro :) it Helped me a lot :)

Comment: My Pleasure to help. Please accept the answer as it is working. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `setSound()` method to set the sound

```
if(!silent) {   // check if phone is not in silent mode
       notificationBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
       NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

       notificationManager.notify(9999, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Or you can use

```
{
    "to" : "XXYYXXYY...",

    "notification" : {
         "body" : "The stock opened on a bullish note at Rs. 449 and touched a high of Rs. 461.35, up 5.06 per cent over its previous closing price on the BSE. A similar movement was seen on the NSE where the stock opened at Rs. 450 and hit a high of Rs. 463.70, up 5.32 per cent.",
         "title" : "Stocks in focus: Kalpataru Power, Punj Lloyd, J B Chem, Bharti Airtel",
         "icon" : "ic_stock",
         "sound" : "res_notif_sound"
    }
 }
```

> If you want to use default sound of the device, you should use:
>   "sound": "default".

Comment: @JackN, unable to understand your comment

Comment: res_notif_sound is system file? and If we want to refer to a file in res folder. how to do that?

Comment: Thanks,It helped me a lot.

Comment: @AnuChaudhary Happy to Help ;)