# Flutter Firebase Cloud Messaging Custom Sound

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to play a custom alert sound when I receive a notification from Firebase Cloud Messaging in Flutter, is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: This may help you:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47787267/fcm-custom-notification-sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47787267/fcm-custom-notification-sound)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't checked yet, there is [firebase_messaging plugins](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) which is an available package that you could use.

Try to check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54003722) and [GitHub post](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/523#issuecomment-722240457) as this was discussing about previous issues encountered when using the plugin for making custom sounds in all platforms.