# Custom sound push notification does not work (Flutter)

Tags: push-notification, dart, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
{
  "to": "XXXX",
  "notification": {
    "title": "ASAP Alert",
    "body": "Please open your app"
  },
  "data": {
    "screen": "/Nexpage1",
    "sound": "alarm",
    "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
  }
}
```

Above is my payload for the push notification. I have insert the alarm.mp3 file inside the raw folder, however it still does not give me the alarm sound, i have try for alarm.mp3 also, is there anything wrong with the json? of it because of the code on my dart file?

[image: here's the mp3 file inside the raw file]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Reading [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) it seems that it should be manage automatically (if you didn't use a [notification builder](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/a0e8c27bb60f82ac3dcae6ff1e3926d3b0ea4a69/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/java/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java#L47-L90)) on Android but you have to specify the `.mp3` extension too and put it inside `notification` field and not `data` one..

```
"sound": "alarm.mp3"
```

`iOS` behaves very differently under the hood but you can use a custom sound by setting the `sound:` field in the notification payload too. Anyway `.mp3` is not a valid APN notification file format, and you need to specify also the file extention.

```
"sound": "filename.caf"
```

Follow [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html) in order to forge your custom sound file for your app.

**mp3 is not a valid format**

> **Preparing Custom Alert Sounds**
>
> Local and remote notifications can specify custom alert sounds to be
> played when the notification is delivered. You can package the audio
> data in an aiff, wav, or caf file. Because they are played by the
> system-sound facility, custom sounds must be in one of the following
> audio data formats:
>
> - `Linear PCM`
> - `MA4 (IMA/ADPCM)`
> - `µLaw`
> - `aLaw`
>
> Place custom sound files in your `app bundle` or in the
> `Library/Sounds` folder of your app’s container directory.  Custom
> sounds must be *under 30 seconds* when played.  If a custom sound is
> over that limit, the default system sound is played instead.
>
> You can use the `afconvert` tool to convert sounds. For example, to
> convert the 16-bit linear PCM system sound `Submarine.aiff` to `IMA4`
> audio in a `CAF file`, use the following command in the Terminal app:
>
> ```
> afconvert /System/Library/Sounds/Submarine.aiff ~/Desktop/sub.caf -d ima4 -f caff -v
> ```

For exampole to convert your `mp3` file in a `caf` file you could type in terminal:

```
afconvert -f caff -d LEI16 alarm.mp3 alarm.caf
```

Read this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) in order to have a deep inside of all generic and specific notifciation payload fields.

**UPDATE**

I've tested the Android part and I can confirm that putting your `.mp3` file in `res/raw/` folder the sound is played as documented and expected.

That's my notification payload:

```
{
 "to" : "my_device_token",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "priority" : "high",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Test Notification body for custom sound {{datestamp}}",
     "title": "Custom sound alert.mp3",
     "sound": "alert.mp3"
 }
}
```

[image]

I've tested also the iOS version after converting `.mp3` file to `.caf` file in that way:

```
afconvert -f caff -d LEI16 alert.mp3 alert.caf
```

the same `json` payload with the different filename works:

```
{
 "to" : "my_device_token",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "priority" : "high",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Test Notification body for custom sound {{datestamp}}",
     "title": "Custom sound alert.mp3",
     "sound": "alert.caf"
 }
}
```

Remember to add the file in your `main bundle`.

[image]

That works if the app is terminated or in background.

If you want to show an alert and play a sound when the app is in foreground you have to manage it on `onMessage` event like someone already have told you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53531387/firebase-push-notification-with-custom-sound-flutter), or you can use a [platform-channel](https://flutter.io/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) here to build your own notification with a [Notification.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder) on Android and a [UNNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter?language=objc) on iOS (for example).

**UPDATE**

This issue has been solved. See [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/523#issuecomment-722240457) the official comment:

> Hey all
>
> As part of our roadmap ([#2582](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2582)) we've just shipped a complete rework of
> the firebase_messaging plugin that aims to solve this and many other
> issues.
>
> If you can, please try out the dev release (see the [migration guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/)
> for upgrading and for changes) and if you have any feedback then join
> in the discussion [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/discussions/4023).
>
> Given the scope of the rework I'm going to go ahead and close this
> issue in favor of trying out the latest plugin.
>
> Thanks everyone

Comment: may i know the version of android your device is? because mine is oreo and it still give me the default sound when receiving the notification

Comment: Did you set `sound` inside `notification` and not `data`?

Comment: yea, i copy exactly the one like you did

Comment: @ali I've tried on Android P device and I can confirm that the sound is not the one passed in the notification payload but the default sound. It seems that for api lever >= 26 (Oreo) custom sound doesn't work.

Comment: I've tried on my nexus 5 and it works, yea might be that oreo and above does not support it

Comment: Okay! I've opened an issue. We can track it [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26005).

Comment: @shadowsheep Thanks for the info. Now in the latest update do I need to include the extension name? If yes, then How to handle .caf on iOS and .mp3 on Android separately? I save user tokens on my server to send them notifications and I have no data about what device user is using.

Comment: Do I need to create a notification channel for this?, can I achieve custom sound for my notification even if the app is killed for both ios and android without notification channel and only by these steps?, and if I need to create notification channels then how can I achieve that in IOS, please?

Comment: To add `IOS` sounds via `xcode` use that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43129166/12695188

Comment: Is it possible to have sound with .caf files for android? In my case it does not work .caf files for android.

Comment: How we can have .caf extension to work for both?

Comment: How do we add to "main bundle"?

Answer (score 8):

ShadowSheep did a good job at answering this question, but there's one thing I want to clarify for trying to get the iOS sounds to work.

You have to add the sound into XCode (which is where ShadowSheep speaks of including the asset inside of the `main bundle`). You can just drag and drop the audio file (in .caf or other supported format mentioned above) into the root directory (usually called Runner for Flutter) in XCode:

[image: Xcode Image]

If you have done this and follow the setup described in the above question/answer, you should be in business.

Answer (score 6):

For me I am using the [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) to create the notification channel.

include this function (may create multiple notification channel)

```
Future<void> _createNotificationChannel(String id, String name,
String description, String sound) async {
final flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
var androidNotificationChannel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  id,
  name,
  description,
  sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound(sound),
  playSound: true,
);

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
    .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
    AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
    ?.createNotificationChannel(androidNotificationChannel);}
```

call the function in initState: (this created 2 notification channel)

```
_createNotificationChannel("channel_id_1", "channel_name", "description", "alert");
_createNotificationChannel("channel_id_2", "channel_name", "description", "alarm");
```

Remember to save the file of `alert` and `alarm` in the `res/raw` in file format of `.mp3`.

with this payload :

```
{
"notification": {
    "title": "My First Notification",
    "body": "Hello, I'm push notification"
},
"data": {
    "title": "My First Notification"
},
"android": {
    "notification": {
        "channel_id": "channel_id_1"
    }
},
"to": "device_token"}
```

Comment: what about IOS?

Comment: Will this work even when the app is in the background or terminated state ??

Comment: @L.Goyal yes it suppose to work when the app not open.. sorry for late response

Comment: that works for Android, but not for IOS looks like (in background)

Answer (score 3):

For the people who try to make custom sound for both android and ios [good guide here](https://nativescripting.com/posts/nativescript-custom-push-notification-sounds):

For iOS:

> To add a custom sound for iOS, add the audio clip for iOS to your
> project's App_Resources/iOS/ directory (iOS only accepts .wav, .aiff,
> and .caf extensions).

For Android:

> First, add the audio clip to your project's
> App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/raw/ directory ((Android only
> accepts .wav, .mp3 and .ogg extensions).

So we can use .wav file in order to use custom sound available for both platform:

```
"notification": {
            "body": "Test notification",
            "title": "Test Test Test",
            "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
           
            "sound": "your_custom_sound.wav" 
            "android_channel_id": "channel_id_youcreated",
},

          'to':
              "",
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

after try this solution in Android I still can't change with custom sound. You need .ogg file type to resolve this issue. After changed to .ogg file type, I can change with custom sound. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32058756)

Answer (score 0):

## The only guide you will ever need

### Android setup

Firstly create an extra notification channel with

```dart
  // channel for default notifications
  const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'wave_remote_notifications', // id
      'Wave messages and updates', // title
      description: 'Primary channel for notifications and messages in wave app',
      importance: Importance.max,
    );
   
   // channel for custom sound  
   const AndroidNotificationChannel channelAudio = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'wave_remote_notifications_priority', // id
      'Wave messages and updates on priority', // title
      description: 'Primary channel for notifications and messages in wave app',
      sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('mario'),
      importance: Importance.max,
    );
    
    
    // if you use flutter_local_notification 
    
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channelAudio);
```

you can see we have added  `RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('mario')`

Now add mp3/wav file into **res/raw/yourmp3files.mp3**

now notification will work but only for debug mode as this file you added will not be included in release mode

So after that you need to add keep.xml inside `res/raw/keep.xml` to include yourmp3files.mp3 into build [keep.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlhMZ.png)

```dart
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@raw/yourmp3files"
    />
```

### iOS setup

You have to add the sound into XCode. You can just drag and drop the audio file (in .caf or .wav supported format ) into the root directory (usually called Runner for Flutter) in XCode

That's all

### FCM Payload

final step

```dart
{
    "to": "f31vmSf8Qy2N57_33C9cf3:APA91bHBaz7yyRrKQTr_25mLNK2OVlBjdMqM8ux8kQwaeQcsXE6XnOhio7Tp5-CABTFTSbV1vBqqfIVj9Qd9eUdqNi9oojq8FdOWI-l1CU9Xw16-Xb4ZHVTycOM7nIRudIAmMkU6fjbm",
    // "collapse_key": "type_a",
    "priority": "high",
    "notification": {
        "title": "New visitor request",
        "body": "Answer to accept",
        "sound": "mario.wav",
        "android_channel_id": "wave_remote_notifications_priority"
    },
    "data": {
        "title": "New visitor request",
        "body": "Answer to accept ",
        "sound": "mario",
    },
    "content_available": true,
    "apns": {
        "payload": {
            "aps": {
                "mutable-content": 1,
                "content-available": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```