# How to dynamically manage files inside the raw folder in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, file, raw

I need to dynamically manage files. I initially tried placing them in the raw folder, but it seems static and not suitable for dynamic handling. What would be the recommended approach for dynamically managing and accessing files inside raw in a Flutter app?

Comment: What exactly do u mean by dynamic handling here ? 
You can not modify the content of a file which is pre-bundled in source. Use local storage for file handling if you want to create/edit files.

Comment: @ADM For push notification custom tones, I would like to add audio files here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54002617/custom-sound-push-notification-does-not-work-flutter/54003722#54003722

Comment: @ADM But it is a manual adding process, but I want to add dynamically while in app running state