# How can a customised sound be set for Android Push Notifications?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, push-notification, notifications

I have recently learnt how to send firebase cloud messages to Flutter, and today I learnt that a notification channel is the way to set an icon for the notifications presented on android devices.  I am now interested in how to set a customised sound for push notifications on android devices.  At present, no sound is heard when notifications are received.

I have sounds intended for android push notifications in the .m4a format within res/raw.

If I were to take a similar step for introducing notification-sound compared with the notification-icon, then I would add details to the notification-channel or adjust the AndroidNotificationDetails object.  This would be fairly simple.

Looking at the AndroidNotificationDetails object, it has a property called 'sound' with an AndroidNotificationSound type.  Something tells me that this AndroidNotificationSound object cannot be a string of directions to a sound file.  I could be wrong, but something tells me that it won't be so simple.

If you are familiar with the AndroidNotificationDetails and you know how to set a notification sound, could you confirm an example of the way please?

And generally, is there a way for introducing sound to Android push notifications that you can show me please?

Comment: This answer could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/54003722/13755145

Comment: Thank you for response @Jannik.  I think the answer there relates to Firebase's Legacy API for Cloud Messaging, however, that API deprecates soon and Firebase will have an alternative way.  Also, I've more or less understood now that payload entries are secondary to the initialisation of a channel.  So, I'm thinking that the ideal answer will not involve a payload.

Comment: I found that the changes forced by Android Studio were very helpful in terms of things working as set.  After being left with no choice but to adopt SDK 34, the settings for sound in push notifications suddenly began to work.  And so this one's resolved : )  And I really really didn't want to move on to level 34, but it turns out to be the best thing.